Configure custom OAuth2 provider with Spring Security 5
I am in the process of migrating the Spring Boot version from 1.5 to 2.7, as well as the Spring Security version to 5.
I have a WebSSO authentication managed by a custom provider, and I have filled in the parameters in the application.yml
I have a problem: when I launch the application, it starts up, the login screen appears, I successfully authenticate, but after the redirection, an auto-generated page by Spring shows up with a link to my custom provider.
I would like to no longer display this auto-generated page.
I'm showing you my setup.
 application-dev.yml

spring:
    security:
        oauth2:
            client:
                registration:
                    my-oidc:
                        provider: custom-provider-id
                        client-id: yyyyy
                        client-secret: :xxxxxx
                        client-authentication-method: basic
                        authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
                        redirect-uri: https://w.x.y.z:8044/app-name/login
                        scope: openid,isMemberOf,gardianSesameProfil
                        client-name: my-custon-provider-id

                provider:
                    gardian:
                        issuer-uri: ${gardian.issuer}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }


}


P.I : the backend and the frontend are in the same package !
Any help please !
